# Should you always use the latest SDK Version when building for iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I can't find this information anywhere in the documentation or online. If I'm wrong can you please provide a link. I have the option of building with SDK Version 11.3 and SDK Version 8.3.

[image]

This is an old app that I'm updating. I assume the right thing to do is to use 11.3 but I can't find any documentation that says to do that.

Answer (score 2):

From your screenshot, the SDK Version is the base SDK which project used. The Base SDK should usually be set to "Latest iOS" (which also means Default in Xamarin).

It specifies the highest version of iOS that your app supports. When your app runs on a device that is running your app's Base SDK, it runs the full feature set available in your app.

There's no need to set it to lower version, if you want your app to support lower iOS version you should set the **Deployment Target** in info.plist.

More details about these two feature's differences, you can refer to: [Base SDK and Deployment Target Settings](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Configuring/configuring.html)

Comment: Hi user875234, is this helpful for you?